# Problem computing an angle

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the following drawning:

[image]

sorry if I did it by hand. In this case, how do I compute the angle $\gamma$?

If I have understood well, it should be:

$\gamma=atan2(y,x)-\theta$

but I am not sure.

Comment: If $\theta$ contains the angle $\gamma$, presumably you could do $\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ to find the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the angle between the line from the point to the origin and the $x$-axis is $\arctan\big(\frac{y}{x}\big)$. Thus, $\boxed{\gamma = \theta-\arctan\big(\frac{y}{x}\big)}$. If you are working on the whole coordinate plane, you should use the $\text{atan2}$ function instead of $\arctan$, which gives the correct angle for all $4$ quadrants.